# How to reset position when reached the border

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

What I'm trying to do is to make the snake *(since im making a snake game)* reset its position when it has reached the border. But with my code, Instead the position of the snake will not reset when it reaches the border, and it'll just go over the border.

```
def move(self):
    cur = self.get_head_position()
    x, y = self.direction
    new = (((cur[0] + (x * gridsize))), (cur[1] + (y * gridsize)))
    if len(self.positions) > 2 and new in self.positions[2:]:
        self.reset()
    else:
        self.positions.insert(0, new)
        if len(self.positions) > self.length:
            self.positions.pop()



screen_width = 520
screen_height = 520

gridsize = 20
grid_width = screen_width / gridsize
grid_height = screen_height / gridsize
```

Any help would be much appreciated!, *(if i reply late im sorry, its most likely because im asleep)*

Comment: It reset its position and score when the snake overlaps itself

Comment: The code does work but the snake would just go over the border, and its position wouldn't reset

Comment: The problem is, I currently have no code to make the snake reset when it touches the border.

Comment: seems like you're testing whether the snake is eating itself not whether it's left the map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to test if the snake is in the grid and invoke `reset()`:

```py
grid_x = new[0] // gridsize
grid_y = new[1] // gridsize
if not (0 <= grid_x < grid_width and 0 <= grid_y < grid_height):
    self.reset()
```

Comment: Thank you for actually answering! this saved me a ton of minutes, anyways, I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

border check

```
if (cur[0] >= 0 and cur[0] <= grid_width) and (cur[1] >= 0 and cur[1] <= grid_height):
    # we are within the borders
else:
    # we are not within the borders
```

you may want to split the if statement up so that you can tell where the snake has left